# Silverlight async calls and anonymous methods

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, delegates

I know there are a couple of debates on this kind of thing.
At any rate, I have several cases where I need to populate ComboBox items based on enumerations returned from the WCF service.

In an effort to keep code clean, I started this approach. After looking into it more, I don't think the this works as well is initially thought...

I am throwing this out to get recommendations/advice/code snippets on how you would do this or how you currently do this.

I may be forced to have a seperate, non anonymous method, procedure.  I hate doing this for something like this but at the moment, don't see it working another way...

```
EventHandler<GetEnumerationsForTypeCompletedEventArgs> ev = delegate(object eventSender, GetEnumerationsForTypeCompletedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (eventArgs.Error == null)
    {
        //comboBox.ItemsSource = eventArgs.Result;
        //populate combox for display purposes (for now)
        foreach (Enumeration e in eventArgs.Result)
        {
            ComboBoxItem cbi = new ComboBoxItem();
            cbi.Content = e.EnumerationValueDisplayed;
            comboBox.Items.Add(cbi);
        }
        // remove event so we don't keep adding new events each time we need an enumeration
        proxy.GetEnumerationsForTypeCompleted -= ev;
    }
};
proxy.GetEnumerationsForTypeCompleted += ev;
proxy.GetEnumerationsForTypeAsync(sEnumerationType);
```

Basically in this example we use ev to hold the anonymous method so we can then use ev from within the method to remove it from the events once called.  This prevents this method from getting called more than one time.

I suspect that the ComboBox local var declared before this call, but within the same method, is not always the ComboBox originally intended but can't really verify that yet.  I may add a tag to it to do some tests and populating to verify.

Sorry if this is not clear.  I can elaborate more if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem that you are having? Are items not added to the ComboBox?

Comment: Please elaborate. It is not clear what problem you are encountering. Expanding the code sample to include the entire method might also be helpful so that we can see where the comboBox variable is declared and assigned.

Comment: KISS. Keep it simple stupid. 

You do not need to use an anonymous method to fill a combo box with data. A simple delegate on the async call and a for each loop is sufficient. 

As an added bonus it will also be completely clear for the next programmer.

Comment: The issue with having a seperate method and using a delegate is that I would need to pass the combobox needing populated as a parameter or global or something so the method knows what to fill.
In my case I could have to fill 30 different comboboxes, so this in effect, makes things more straight forward.

The issue here is that the comboboxes are getting filled with the same results instead of the intended results.  It's as if the last call fills all the comboboxs with the same data instead of each call only populating that ONE combobox.  I will revise little more to make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The way I came to do it is like so :

```
var query = from t in GetFreshContext().Employee select t;
var dsQuery = (DataServiceQuery<Employee>)query;
dsQuery.BeginExecute(result =>
{
    ComboEmployees.ItemsSource = dsQuery.EndExecute(result).ToArray();
}, null);
ComboEmployees.DisplayMemberPath = "FullName";
```

I wrote a [blog post regarding some other problems and this](http://blog.andrei.rinea.ro/post/2009/08/19/Using-ADONET-Data-Servics-in-Silverlight-3-and-eager-loading-parent-entities.aspx).